# Completion of a measure space and Null Sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a confusion on the completion of a measure space:

I understand its definition being the addition of subsets of Null Sets to the original measure, but I don't understand is

1.why are these subsets not present a priori 
2.where do the "completing" null sets come from?

An example is the fact that the Borel measure is incomplete, but the Lebesgue forms its completion. Is there a concrete example of a Lebesgue measurable set that is not Borel measurable?

Thanks!

Comment: The most well known example deals with the Cantor function, which you can look up on here or in any measure theory text. Completing your measure isn't always a good thing as this example shows. The sets forming the complete measure space come from unions of sets in your original sigma algebra and unions of the null sets that weren't measurable before. Sometimes theorems rely on measures being complete as a technical point (e.g. when dealing with Brownian motion) You can show that if $X$ has the same distribution as $E(X | G)$, then $X$ is measurable with respect to the completion of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

There are models of set theory not satisfying AC where all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are Borel, so we can't really find an "explicit" example of a Lebesgue measurable non-Borel set.

However we can do some simple examples: let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ be a set with three points, $\Omega=\{\varnothing,\{1,2\},\{3\},X\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu(X)=\mu\{3\}=1$, $\mu\{1,2\}=\mu\varnothing=0$.

The completion of $(\Omega,\mu)$ consists of the $\sigma$-algebra $\tilde{\Omega}=\mathcal{P}(X)$, the power set of $X$, and the measure $\tilde{\mu}(A)=\begin{cases}1&\text{, if }3\in A\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.